# How do I make my single-work page show on my front-page.php?

Tags: homepage, frontpage

How do I make my single-work page show on my `front-page.php`?

So I want to show my `work` page on the homepage. For example, my work page link is `www.example.com/work` but I want to show the work page in `www.example.com`. Should I use gettemplate code?

Answer (score 1):

No CODE is necessary for this.

Go to WordPress Admin Panel → `Settings` → `Reading`.

Then from the option `Your homepage displays`, select `A static page (select below)` & then in the `Homepage:` dropdown menu, select your `Work` page & <kbd>Save Changes</kbd>.

Like the screenshot below:

[image: Select a static page as home page].

Of course, once you've done this, your `Work` page content will be loaded on the site home page (e.g. `www.example.com`) with proper home page template (e.g. `front-page.php`) of your theme.

Check the [Template Hierarchy document](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#home-page-display) to learn which theme template will handle the home page in different situations.

### Custom Home Page Template

Say you have a [template file](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) (within the theme) named `single-work.php` and another template file `front-page.php`. According to WordPress template hierarchy, `front-page.php` will load the home page, regardless of the setting `Your latest posts` or `A static Page`.

You can change that if you choose `A static page`. Let's say you have a static page named `Work` & you select this page as your `Homepage`. Now, first, put the following CODE at the top of `single-work.php` template file:

```
<?php
    /* Template Name: Work Template */
```

Then edit `work` page and you'll see the Template selection option under `Page Attributes`:

[image: custom template]

From there, select `Work Template` and save. That way, the home page will load using `single-work.php` template instead of `front-page.php`.

> **Note:** if you don't see the `Page Attributes` meta box, then select `Page Attributes` from top right `Screen Options` drop down menu.

Comment: Thank you but when I checked the "a static page" and for homepage and post page I can't see "work" My single-work.php is not showing there. I use custom field for my work page.

Comment: i have single-work.php . I need to name it like that because it's a blog. I just want my blog to show in the homepage. Is there another to do that?

Comment: I also have a archive-work.php .

Comment: Ok, I select Your latest posts but is not showing on my front-page.php . Do you know why?

Comment: yes it's in my theme folder.

Comment: do i need to type any code to display single-work.php to my front-page.php?

Comment: I follow your instruction and I create a page called Work and add the template name too. But right now work will show up in static page. My single page is front page now but there is no content on the front page.

Comment: Content will not come automatically, copy CODE from another existing template, say `home.php` or `index.php` and then modify them as necessary.

Comment: i want my code from single-work.php to show on my front-page.php. but if i copy the code from single-work.php, does that mean i'm not using the single-work.php?

Comment: OK, if all you want is the same CODE from ` single-work.php` on `front-page.php`, then you simply copy that CODE, yes. Also, since WordPress template hierarchy has no special meaning for naming like `single-work.php`, that means you are not using `single-work.php` file anymore (unless that file is selected as a custom template for a page).

Comment: Please study [WordPress Theme Development guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/), otherwise you'll have a lot of confusions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file as named `work.php` in your theme directory folder and add this code top of the file:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Work
Template Post Type: page
*/
?>

Your codes here...
```

Go -> Pages, edit your Work page. And select page template as `Work`

And go reading settings. Select front page as `Work`